# How to download all Google Drive files for all users in my organization

Tags: export, google-drive, offline-files

I am a super-admin for my organization and I would like to download all Google Drive files for every user in my organization in order to have an offline copy of all information. These files may or may not be shared with me. It's okay if this is a manual operation, however it would be better if it could be automated. I do not want to go the route of having to have all documents shared with me so I can see all of the docs. I would rather just download all files in sub folders based on the users in my organization.

I've taken a look at Google Takeout but that needs to be done user by user. I've looked at Backupify, but that creates a backup, not a copy of the files I can download. I've looked at DriveExport, but that requires a Google Cloud Platform account which I do not have. Are there any other solutions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can download entire directories as a compressed .zip on Google Drive, as long as it's shared with you.

There should be an option titled "Download All" somewhere in the Drive options.

**See this question for some further insight:**

[Download all folders from a shared Google Drive folder](https://superuser.com/questions/836778/download-all-folders-from-a-shared-google-drive-folder)

***Edit***: Not sure how you plan on accessing other people's stuff without their permission? You'll need to get sharing privileges/permission from the users. You won't be able to just download people's stuff without consent. You should have that access since you're a super-admin, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I would like to do this for all folders for all users of my organization, even if the folders are not shared with me. The company owns all of the data anyway. When they signed the employee handbook when hired, they forfeited rights to all of the data on company computers.

Comment: Does Google know about this? You could send a message to Google explaining you have all the rights, and then see if you can get them that way.

Comment: Stupid comment box. Anyway, I was going to say, try contacting each user manually and getting the permissions that way.